# Install Cloudera and Hadoop on ubuntu 16

Tags: hadoop, cloudera-manager

I am trying to find online materials to find the steps or guideline on installing cloudera and Hadoop. I found [this](http://blogs.data-flair.com/install-cloudera-hadoop-cdh5-ubuntu/) and [this](http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cdh_ig_cdh5_install.html) page but none of them helped.

If you know please help me on this as I am new to Ubuntu 16 as well as Cloudera and Hadoop.

Comment: It doesn't look like you actually provided the URLs for the steps and guidelines you mentioned.

Comment: Yea I did forget to, added the links now. Thanks

Comment: I have tried with both links and installed Hadoop successfully, What was the issue/error you were facing can you post ?

Comment: I am also facing problems with uabntu 16.
I think we need to install uabntu 14.04 LTS untill cloudera release never version for 16

Comment: Did you install it?